# Monitoring SES delivery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have implemented SES in one of my application. Currently the I have implemented is that using SDK I wait for the success/failure response and take action based on the response. Now, I want to make is async so the process does not have to wait for the response and if any failure happen I should be able to see it and resend the email.

I have following questions.

- I checked the CloudTrial does not support SendEmail or SendRawEmail then where can I see the status of an email whether its sent or not?
- I read that SES makes the first attempt to send an email within few milliseconds. Does it retries if the first attempt was a failure or the SES was out of service?
- Is there a better way of achieving what I want to achieve?
- Can I see the SES queue anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can [sign up to receive](https://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx1HC8RUEM1UC66/Announcing-Delivery-Notifications) Bounces, Complaints and Delivery notifications via SNS. That's all you can do. You can't see the SES queue or get any other visibility into SES besides what the SNS notifications give you.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon will make several attempts to deliver your e-mails to the recipients.
The big thing is that they will not give you the bounce notification until 12-24 hours later in my experience.  This is due to them retrying to send the mail a few times, waiting for mail hosts to be available, etc.

If you use SES you should use their SNS system to check for bounces, complaints, and delivery notifications.  That way you can handle the failed deliveries in a graceful manner.

Amazon's Doc here gives you some insight into how it works
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email-with-ses.html